# Using decode to check for negative and positive values

Tags: sql

Hi is there a way to use decode to check for positive and negative values in sql?

e.g.

```
select decode(money_return, **<0**, abs(money_return), **>0**, 
money_return*10, money_return) from cash_t;
```

if the logic is coded in if else statement it will be something like this:

```
if(money_return<0){money_reutrn = abs(money_return);}
else if(money_return>0){money_reutrn = money_return*10;}
else {money_return = money_return;}
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need case statement

```
select CASE 
 WHEN money_return < 0 THEN abs(money_return)
 WHEN money_return > 0 THEN money_return*10
 ELSE money_return END money_return from cash_t;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use 'sign' with a decode.  Sign will return -1 for any negative, 0 for 0, and 1 for any positive:

```
select decode(sign(money_return), -1, abs(money_return), 
                                   1, money_return*10, 
                                   money_return) 
from cash_t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SIGN(). It returns "0" for 0, "1" for positive and "-1" for negative values.

```
SELECT
    DECODE(
        SIGN(money_return),
        0,
        money_return,
        1,
        money_return * 10,
        - 1,
        ABS(money_return)
    )
FROM
    CASH_T;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as like this,

```
SELECT supplier_name,
decode(supplier_id, 10000, 'IBM',
                    10001, 'Microsoft',
                    10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
                    'Gateway') result
FROM suppliers;
```

The above decode statement is equivalent to the following IF-THEN-ELSE statement:

```
IF supplier_id = 10000 THEN
   result := 'IBM';

ELSIF supplier_id = 10001 THEN
   result := 'Microsoft';

ELSIF supplier_id = 10002 THEN
   result := 'Hewlett Packard';

ELSE
   result := 'Gateway';

END IF;
```

So your final code should be something like this,

```
select decode(money_return, money_return<0, abs(money_return),
                            money_return>0, money_return*10,
                                            money_return) result
from cash_t;
```

Comment: @rs. He is asking is there is a way to use decode to check for positive and negative values in sql? He is not aware of DECODE I guess. See there is a wrong syntax in his question

Comment: Mind to share which part is wrong for the decode part? maybe typo error?

Comment: @user1872384 You can not use '**<0**' like this in decode function. I hope so. Can you check and let me know if it works in your environment

Comment: That's the reason for creating this topic. lol... Because I am not sure how to use <0 and >0, that's why it's in bold **<0** **>0**. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @user1872384 hey buddy, your requirement is to use decode function right.? Out of curiosity am asking why did you choose 'case when' as a proper answer??

Comment: Apparently select decode(money_return, money_return<0, abs(money_return),
                            money_return>0, money_return*10,
                                            money_return) result
from cash_t; will not work. I've tried it even before creating this topic itself. At first I thought it should work as well. And since the case method by rs solved the problem, why not accept it as an answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21704/discussion-between-mari-and-user1872384)

Answer (score 1):

I use function "greatest" and "least" found Positive values or Negative value.

example.

> select decode(greatest(value,0), 0,'Negative','Positive') from dual

or

> select decode(least(value,0), 0,'Positive','Negative') from dual

thank

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE money_return  
  WHEN money_return < 0 THEN abs(money_return) 
  WHEN money_return > 0 THEN money_return*10
  ELSE money_return END money_return from cash_t;
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the advantage for including money_return after the CASE statement?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only formula you use, you could do:

```
select (11 *abs(money_return) + 9 *money_return)/2 as money_return
from cash_t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5027f/2) to check the results.

Now, this is very, very fragile, and won't work if the scenario changes.

Comment: Please, do you the `case` code in production. It's much more clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    decode(
        money_return - Abs(money_return),
        0,
        money_return * 10,
        abs(money_return)
    )
FROM
    cash_t;
```

If the value is positive, deducting it from itself will return 0 and the first condition will be applied. Else, it is negative and the second condition is applied. 0 Will fit into the first condition and return 0 (as 0*10).

Comment: Need to absolute the subtracted value or this equation will always return zero.  

select decode(:money_return-abs(:money_return), 0, :money_return*10, abs(:money_return)) 
from dual;